# How to merge two columns based on the same data

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I'd like to merge two columns based on the same data on one column. Please see attached image.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyXke.png)

Could anyone help me with this?

Edit: I need to know how to fill in my Quantity column with the relevant amounts from a separate table.  So, I want a formula that looks at "apple", then gets the number from a separate table and fills in.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: if you have never done a step with pivot tables, you could get your first experience with it (assuming there will come more and more data while the time runs by) ...would also provide a way to keep track of each add... just a recommendation :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need a `Vlookup` formula.  Enter this in `I2` and drag down:

`=Vlookup(H2,$B$16:$C$18,2,False)`

The range B16:C18 should be the range of your table. I think I got it right, but you may need to adjust.

Edit: This will leave errors for fruits without amounts.  Use this formula instead, `=Iferror(Vlookup(H2,$B$16:$C$18,2,False),"")`